# How can I create a new case in switch statement that depends on the previous case

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, switch-statement, local-storage

Working fiddle of the what I am trying to do :
https://jsfiddle.net/wymn7g6s/

The category and products drop down are working using a switch statement.

**What I want to do is :**

Add a new case called Wattage. 
The user selects a product and a respective wattage for that product is displayed everytime.

below is my attempt at pseudo code

```
    function configureDropDownLists(category, products) {
      //var appliances = {
      //refrigerators:  [ 'Artic King AEB', 'Artic King ATMA', 'Avanti Compact', 'Bosch SS'],

      //dishWasher:    ['Bosch - SHXUC', 'Asko DS', 'Blomberg', 'Amana']
      //  }


      var refrigerators = new Array('Artic King AEB', 'Artic King ATMA', 'Avanti Compact', 'Bosch SS');
      var dishWasher = new Array('Bosch - SHXUC', 'Asko DS', 'Blomberg', 'Amana');


      switch (category.value) {
        case 'refrigerators':
          products.options.length = 0;
          for (i = 0; i < refrigerators.length; i++) {
            createOption(products, refrigerators[i], refrigerators[i]);
          }
          break;
        case 'dishWasher':
          products.options.length = 0;
          for (i = 0; i < dishWasher.length; i++) {
            createOption(products, dishWasher[i], dishWasher[i]);
          }
          break;

        default:
          products.options.length = 0;
          break;
      }



    }


    function createOption(ddl, text, value) {
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.value = value;
      opt.text = text;
      ddl.options.add(opt);
    }



    /*

    Added on MAY 6th 1:29 PM

    Store and display Wattage based on the product selected

    1) Define wattage array

    2) get wattage array

    3) Check for which product is selected and accordingly display the Wattage. This has to happen onChange of the products dropdown. 



    // define wattage array
    var wattageArray = localStorage {
      Artic King AEB: 270, 
      Artic King  ATMA: 311, 
      Avanti Compact:340, 
      Bosch SS: 214,
      Bosch - SHXUC: 200,
      Asko DS: 187,
      Blomberg: 236,
      Amana: 150
     };  
     



    function getWattageArray() {

    var wattageArray = getWattageArray();
     
    // loop and check for key, value

     for (var i = 0; i < wattageArray.length; i++) {
      var key = wattageArray[i];
      var value = wattageArray[i];
      
     var wattageArray = localStorage.getItem("wattageArray");
     
     // check for products drop down and compare it to wattage
      for (options.selectedIndex == wattageArray) {
      
     // display using innerHTML. Parse it since it is an integer
      var value = parseInt(localStorage.getItem[i]));
      document.getElementById("wattage").innerHTML = value;
    }
    }
     SIMPLE SET and DISPLAY TO SEE IF LOCAL STORAGE WORKS
     
      //localStorage.setItem("Artic King AEB",270);
      //localStorage.setItem("Artic King  ATMA",311);
      
      //localStorage.setItem("Avanti Compact",340);
      //localStorage.setItem("Bosch SS",214);
      //localStorage.setItem("Bosch - SHXUC",200);
      
      //localStorage.setItem("Asko DS",187);
      //localStorage.setItem("Blomberg",236);
      //localStorage.setItem("Amana",150);
      
      //var sticky = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("Blomberg"));
      //alert(sticky);







    function estimatedDailyUse(dailyUse){

    var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
      console.log(button);
      
      if(button.onclick.id =="h1"){
        return dailyUse = 1;
        alert("You clicked one");
        console.log("hi");
         }
     
      else if (button.onclick.id =="h3"){
        return dailyUse = 3;
      
      }
      
      else if (button.onclick.id =="h6"){
        return dailyUse = 6;
      
      
      }
      else if (button.onclick.id =="h24"){
        return dailyUse = 24;
      }
     
     }
     
     /*
     
     function selectOption(ddl,text,value){
     
      document.getElementById("product").onchange = function() {
            this.selectedIndex ==selected;
               }        
        }
     
     if(category.value == selected){
      
     }
     
     
     if so and so option is selected in Category 
      make that option as selected
      populate products

     if so and so option is selected by user in products 
      make that option as selected
      display wattage 

     
     
     }
     
    $(function() {
        var categoryValue = localStorage.getItem("categoryValue");
        if(categoryValue != null) {
            $("select[name=ddl]").val(categoryValue);
        }

        $("select[name=ddl]").on("change", function() {
            localStorage.setItem("categoryValue", $(this).val());
        });
    })
     
     
      
     */

    /*

    How to store and display Wattage based on the product selected

    1) Define wattage array

    2) get wattage array

    3) Check for which product is selected and accordingly display the Wattage. This has to happen onChange of the products dropdown. 



    // define wattage array
    var wattageArray = localStorage {
      Artic King AEB: 270, 
      Artic King  ATMA: 311, 
      Avanti Compact:340, 
      Bosch SS: 214,
      Bosch - SHXUC: 200,
      Asko DS: 187,
      Blomberg: 236,
      Amana: 150
     };  
     
    // call wattage array inside init

    window.onload = init;

    function init() {
     
     //options.onchange = displayWattage;

     var wattageArray = getWattageArray();
     
     for (var i = 0; i < wattageArray.length; i++) {
      var key = wattageArray[i];
      var value = wattageArray[i];
      
     } 
    }

    function getWattageArray() {
     var wattageArray = localStorage.getItem("wattageArray");
     
     for (options.selectedIndex == wattageArray) {
      
      var value = parseInt(localStorage.getItem[i]));
      document.getElementById("wattage").innerHTML = value;
    }
    }
     SIMPLE SET and DISPLAY TO SEE IF LOCAL STORAGE WORKS
     
      //localStorage.setItem("Artic King AEB",270);
      //localStorage.setItem("Artic King  ATMA",311);
      
      //localStorage.setItem("Avanti Compact",340);
      //localStorage.setItem("Bosch SS",214);
      //localStorage.setItem("Bosch - SHXUC",200);
      
      //localStorage.setItem("Asko DS",187);
      //localStorage.setItem("Blomberg",236);
      //localStorage.setItem("Amana",150);
      
      //var sticky = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("Blomberg"));
      //alert(sticky);
     
     
     */
```

Also how do I keep my drop downs selected (once the user has completed selection of the product.)

Thanks

Comment: I realize that it's pseudo-code, but you should fix the syntax so that it formats nicely.

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't seem to be able to handle the initial functionality of checking the category and populating the second dropdown with products. I see you have product arrays set up, and your function is defined, but when is the function actually called and executed? ** edit - I see that it is being called now, but it is undefined :/

Comment: Okay, so [I've got your code somewhat working so that the dropdowns are functional](https://jsfiddle.net/cwyk2o1q/1/), but I think you are going to have to rethink how you will go about this. You want the wattage to change every time a user selects a product, right? But this function in which you want to add the code is only called whenever the **category** is changed. So you'll want to define a separate function that is called whenever the value of the **product** input changes.

Comment: thanks a lot for checking . You are right I want the wattage to change every time the user selects a product. I am nwebie to JS and to coding in genreal.

Comment: can you explain more about that new function please. In the meanwhile I have tried to make a new function and update the pseudo with date and time. Sorry this is messy. I am like a lawyer trying to write a cookbook.

Comment: I just provided an example with some explanation in my answer below. Check it out and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This should be pretty close to what you're looking for](https://jsfiddle.net/cwyk2o1q/4/). As I said in my comment above, you'll have to rethink how you're structuring these functions. The `configureDropDownLists` function you made is only called whenever the category changes. If you want wattage to change whenever a new product is selected, you will need to put that in a separate function that is executed whenever the product value is updated.

Here is the updated JS:

```
var category = document.getElementById('ddl'),
    product = document.getElementById('products'),
    wattage = document.getElementById('wattage'),
    refrigerators = new Array('Artic King AEB', 'Artic King ATMA', 'Avanti Compact', 'Bosch SS'),
    dishWasher = new Array('Bosch - SHXUC', 'Asko DS', 'Blomberg', 'Amana');

var productChange = function() {
    switch (product.value) {
        case 'Artic King AEB':
            wattage.innerHTML = 400;
            break;
        case 'Artic King ATMA':
            wattage.innerHTML = 500;
            break;
        default: 
            wattage.innerHTML = 'N/A'
            break;
    }
}

var categoryChange = function() {
    switch (category.value) {
        case 'refrigerators':
            products.options.length = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < refrigerators.length; i++) {
                createOption(products, refrigerators[i], refrigerators[i]);
            }
            break;
        case 'dishWasher':
            products.options.length = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < dishWasher.length; i++) {
                createOption(products, dishWasher[i], dishWasher[i]);
            }
            break;
        default:
            products.options.length = 0;
            break;
    }

    productChange();
}

function createOption(ddl, text, value) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = value;
    opt.text = text;
    ddl.options.add(opt);
}

category.addEventListener('change', categoryChange);

product.addEventListener('change', productChange);
```

You'll notice a few things:

1. I restructured the code so that variables are defined outside of the functions. There's no reason to recreate new local variables every single time these functions are called - they do not change.
2. I defined the two functions, `productChange` and `categoryChange`, independently. This way, they can be called at any time in other places (like in the event listeners I set up). Other than my personal preference for cleaner code (IMO), this allows you to call the `productChange` function within the `categoryChange` function - updating the wattage value on the initial selection of the category. It is later called whenever the user updates the product selection itself.
3. I only added cases for two of the products, with a default case for any other product.
4. I'm not sure if the switch structure will be best here since you're going to be dealing with quite a few product choices. Maybe it would be better to store all of the products with their associated wattages together in one big object so you can just call up the wattage property without having to go through and define each and every single product/wattage combination in a switch statement.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation. Got the explanation of all the points from 1 to 3. For point no of 4 about object I am going to learn about them now and shall try to incorporate them.

Comment: I played with the fiddle . it works Gr8 but when I copy pasted the code to my local machine the products and wattage wont appear. Am I doing something wrong.

Comment: @Accidental_Everything the HTML is updated slightly - did you copy that over as well?

Comment: Yes I did copy the HTML. I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" in the console

Comment: It sounds like the variables are not being defined properly at the beginning. The variable definitions at the beginning were copied over, right? Can you try console.log(category) after those variables are defined and see if it logs out that element correctly?

Comment: I copied the script tag at the end of the HTML and the page worked but I still get the error in the console. Should I carry the global variables inside on load or something

Comment: Yeah... If those variables are getting defined before the DOM loads, it won't work (and will throw that error).

Comment: When I added Console.log(category) I got null , ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null                                          AND <select> tag highlighted.

Comment: I did this                                                                                      window.onload = init;

function init() {
category = document.getElementById('ddl');
product = document.getElementById('products');
wattage = document.getElementById('wattage');
refrigerators = new Array('Artic King AEB', 'Artic King ATMA', 'Avanti Compact', 'Bosch SS');
dishWasher = new Array('Bosch - SHXUC', 'Asko DS', 'Blomberg', 'Amana'); 

}

Comment: I took the script code at the end of the HTML and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Can you guide me how to avoid the dropdowns getting reset issue. Does it involve local storage

Comment: @Accidental_Everything I'm not clear on that issue. When is the selection disappearing?

Comment: As soon as I click on any button my selection disappears.(4 buttons below). Background  - I am trying to write a function to calculate Daily Energy used when I click on any of the four buttons. So these 4 buttons will pass no of days to Daily Energy

Comment: Oh, this is because the browser thinks that all button elements are submit or reset buttons by default unless specified otherwise. You need to specify that they are not those by doing something like `<button type="button" />`. I updated the jsfiddle above.

Comment: awesome. thanks a lot. this was bugging me for so long and i did not know how to explain or correct it. When you get time pl recommend a resource to me which explain Why of JAVASCRIPT not how.